# iOS App crash: "Selector name found in current argument registers: appendDictionary:into:"

Tags: ios, crash, sbjson

My application is crashing sometimes with the following reason. Its coming from SBJSON library.

```
Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: appendDictionary:into:

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x00000001006a5020 -[SBJsonWriter appendDictionary:into:] (SBJsonWriter.m:149)
1   MyApp                           0x00000001006a4b84 -[SBJsonWriter appendValue:into:] (SBJsonWriter.m:86)
2   MyApp                           0x00000001006a4998 -[SBJsonWriter stringWithFragment:] (SBJsonWriter.m:59)
3   MyApp                           0x00000001006a2dec -[NSObject(NSObject_SBJSON) JSONRepresentation] (NSObject+SBJSON.m:48)
```

Any idea what is this crash means? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the error occurs, but I recommend that you upgrade your version of SBJson! (Or switch to NSJSONSerialisation.) There have been many, many, MANY bug fixes since the version you're using. I deleted the NSObject+SBJSON.m file referenced in your stack trace many years ago.